# Why calculate cos on different calculator get different results?

Tags: calculator

I just recently start to learn cos. I found out when I use different calculators to calculate cos, sometimes may get different results which is quite confusing.

For example, cos(35),  I am calculating degrees.

on 1 calculator:[image]

on another calcuator:
[image]

Could anyone explain me why this happens and which one is correct?

It is very confusing for me.

Thanks for any responds.

Comment: Did you mean $35$ degrees or $35$ radians?

Comment: @lulu I think as you

Comment: @lulu, I am calculating degrees

Comment: Do your calculators know that?  $35$ radians is $2005$ degrees.

Comment: @lulu, i don't really know since the calculator doesn't have that option.

Comment: Well, there's the problem then.

Comment: You may be trying to calculate degrees but the second *calculator* is calculator is calculator radians.  $\cos 35^0 = 0.8195204$ but $\cos 35\ radians = -0.90369255$.  That's what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first calculator is doing degrees.  $\cos 35^\circ \approx 0.819$. This is reasonable because $0< 35 < 90$ so the $\sin/\cos$ values will both be positive.  $30 < 35 < 45$ so $\cos 30^\circ =\frac {\sqrt 3}2 > \cos 35^\circ > \cos 45^\circ =\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ so the value $0.819...$ is reasonable.  $-0.9036...$ is not.

The second calculator is doing radians and for radian input $35$ is a strange input but not impossible.  $35 = \frac {35}{\pi} \pi \approx 11.14 \pi$. As trig values repeat every $2\pi$ turns, $\cos 35 = \cos 11.14 \pi = \cos 1.14\pi$.  As $\cos \pi = -1$, we have $\cos 1.14$ will be "kind of" close to $-1$.  And $-0.9036...$ is reasonable for radians.

Alternatively.  $360^\circ = 2\pi \ radians$ so $1\ radian = \frac {360}{2\pi}^\circ$ and $35\ radians = 35\times \frac {360}{2\pi}^\circ \approx 2005.35^\circ$.  As trig values repeat every $360^\circ$, we know $\cos 2005.35^\circ = \cos (5\cdot 360 + 205.35)^\circ = \cos 205.35^\circ = \cos (180^\circ + 25.35^\circ)$.  As $\cos 180 = -1$ then $\cos 205.35$ should be "kind of" close to $-1$ and that's a reasonable answer for $\cos 2005.35^\circ$.

(More guestimation:  $\cos (180 + k)^\circ = - \cos k^\circ$ so $\cos 205^\circ = \cos (180 + 25)^\circ = -\cos 25^\circ$.  As $0 < 25 < 30$ we have $1=\cos 0 > \cos 25 > \cos 30 = \frac {\sqrt 3}2 \approx 0.866$ so $\cos 25^\circ \approx 0.9036...$ is a reasonable answer and $-0.9306...$ is a reasonable answer for $\cos 2005^\circ$.)

tl;dr:  Doing trig with degrees (1 circle = $360^\circ$) and doing trig with radians (1 circle = $2\pi$ radians) will have very different results.  One calculator is using degrees.  The other is using radians.... That's my final answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

On the first calculator the calculator is calibrated to take input in degrees whereas in second it is in radians .